# How to install this Python package from sources?

Tags: python, pip

There is a nuScenes-devkit: https://github.com/nutonomy/nuscenes-devkit
I made some modifications in a private repository and want to install it from source but I can't.
If I do `pip install .` from `setup` folder, I have the following error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /mnt/nvme1n1/venvs/enp2/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-wfs5ujhi/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-wfs5ujhi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-req-build-wfs5ujhi/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-wfs5ujhi/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-wfs5ujhi/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        with open('../README.md', 'r') as fh:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../README.md'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Although, `README.md` certainly exists, I can check it by `vim ../README.md` from the same folder.

UPD: Also I tried `python setup.py install` from `setup` folder. It has the following error:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing requirements to python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/requires.txt
writing top-level names to python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/top_level.txt
error: package directory 'python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit/egg-info' does not exist
```

UPD2: I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Python 3.8.10, pip 22.1.2 (for convenience, I checked Python and pip versions at the end of the instruction of Bastian Venthur). Also, I tried to do it in my own virtual environment, which is also created using python venv.

UPD3: Here is the full error from `pip install -e .` from the answer of Bastian Venthur:

```
Obtaining file:///tmp/nuscenes-devkit/setup
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      running egg_info
      creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-02j0_bgt/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info
      writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-02j0_bgt/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-02j0_bgt/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-02j0_bgt/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-02j0_bgt/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-02j0_bgt/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      error: package directory 'python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit/egg-info' does not exist
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Also, I tried to do it with `sudo pip install -e .`:

```
Obtaining file:///tmp/nuscenes-devkit/setup
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/nuscenes-devkit/setup/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/nuscenes-devkit/setup/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
         cwd: /tmp/nuscenes-devkit/setup/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    running egg_info
    writing python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/top_level.txt
    error: package directory 'python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit/egg-info' does not exist
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Can you please share what OS, Python and pip version you are using?
Also, it seems that you are using virtual environment - what virtualenv tool are you using.
If I'll be able to reproduce the issue I'm sure I can help

Comment: @guyszweigman Hi! I updated my question - I included the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:
Create a `setup.py` file in the root directory of the `nuscenes-devkit` repository with the following content (then, to install, run `pip install .` from the root directory):

```
from pathlib import Path

import setuptools

package_dir = 'python-sdk'
setup_dir = Path(__file__).parent / 'setup'

# Since nuScenes 2.0 the requirements are stored in separate files.
requirements = []
for req_path in (setup_dir / 'requirements.txt').read_text().splitlines():
    if req_path.startswith('#'):
        continue
    req_path = req_path.replace('-r ', '')
    requirements += (setup_dir / req_path).read_text().splitlines()


# Get subfolders recursively

setuptools.setup(
    name='nuscenes-devkit',
    version='1.1.9',
    author='Holger Caesar, Oscar Beijbom, Qiang Xu, Varun Bankiti, Alex H. Lang, Sourabh Vora, Venice Erin Liong, '
           'Sergi Widjaja, Kiwoo Shin, Caglayan Dicle, Freddy Boulton, Whye Kit Fong, Asha Asvathaman, Lubing Zhou '
           'et al.',
    author_email='nuscenes@motional.com',
    description='The official devkit of the nuScenes dataset (www.nuscenes.org).',
    long_description=Path('README.md').read_text(),
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
    url='https://github.com/nutonomy/nuscenes-devkit',
    python_requires='>=3.6',
    install_requires=requirements,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(package_dir),
    package_dir={'': package_dir},
    package_data={'': ['*.json']},
    include_package_data=True,
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'License :: Free for non-commercial use'
    ],
    license='cc-by-nc-sa-4.0'
)
```

**Explanation:**
When running in a virtual environment, pip copies the directory that contains the `setup.py` script to a temporary directory and runs the installation from there. In `nuscenes_devkit`, the `python-sdk` directory which is the root package of the project is not copied to this temporary directory since it's a sibling of the `setup` directory, hence, you get a `FileNotFoundError`.

At any case, having the `setup.py` script in the root directory is definitely the best practice (even better approach would be to use `setup.cfg` file but this is out of scope).

I personally think this issue should be considered as a bug in `nuscenes-devkit`.

So the solution is to move the `setup.py` script to the root directory and align it accordingly (I also took the liberty of using `setuptools.find_packages` to simplify the script).

**Last note:** You may take a look at the [advanced installation](https://github.com/nutonomy/nuscenes-devkit/blob/master/docs/installation.md) doc, the instructions there doesn't mention `pip` or `setup.py`, they suggest modifying `PYTHONPATH` instead. I personally don't like this approach, but it may be an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked for me! Also, pretty clear explanation

Answer (score 0):

Installing **nuscenes-devkit :-**

via pip:-

```
pip install nuscenes-devkit
```

from source:-

```
git clone https://github.com/nutonomy/nuscenes-devkit.git   #clone the repo

cd nuscenes-devkit/setup               #change directory to setup

python setup.py install                #install using setup.py

pip show nuscenes-devkit               #confirm ur installation
```

Comment: I have the following error: `error: package directory 'python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit/egg-info' does not exist`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```bash
cd /tmp/                  # get the package sources from github
git clone https://github.com/nutonomy/nuscenes-devkit.git
cd nuscenes-devkit/
cd setup/

python3 -m venv venv      # provide a clean environment
. venv/bin/activate       # and use it
pip install -e .          # install the package in dev-mode

pip show nuscenes-devkit  # voila
Name: nuscenes-devkit
Version: 1.1.9
Summary: The official devkit of the nuScenes dataset (www.nuscenes.org).
Home-page: https://github.com/nutonomy/nuscenes-devkit
Author: Holger Caesar, Oscar Beijbom, Qiang Xu, Varun Bankiti, Alex H. Lang, Sourabh Vora, Venice Erin Liong, Sergi Widjaja, Kiwoo Shin, Caglayan Dicle, Freddy Boulton, Whye Kit Fong, Asha Asvathaman, Lubing Zhou et al.
Author-email: nuscenes@motional.com
License: cc-by-nc-sa-4.0
Location: /tmp/nuscenes-devkit/python-sdk
Requires: cachetools, descartes, fire, jupyter, matplotlib, numpy, opencv-python, Pillow, pycocotools, pyquaternion, scikit-learn, scipy, Shapely, tqdm
Required-by:
```

Sometimes it helps to upgrade `pip` itself **before** doing the `pip install` dance:

```bash
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: I have this error:
`error: package directory 'python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit/egg-info' does not exist`. But anyway thank you because probably the problem is on my side

Comment: Just to clarify: `pip install --upgrade pip` didn't help too

Comment: Didn't work for me on wsl (ubuntu)

Comment: @adroit.levees.0r can you run exactly the steps as i described above but use `pip install -v -e .` (mind the -v parameter)? this way we might get a more precise error that helps to debug.

Answer (score 0):

When I follow guy szweigman's accepted answer using the `setup.py` file on top level, I still get the error message below.

Insights appreciated if this is another error of nuscenes-devkit or of setuptools in general.

```
Running setup.py develop for nuscenes-devkit
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error
    
    × python setup.py develop did not run successfully.
    │ exit code: 1
    ╰─> [66 lines of output]
        running develop
        /home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py:40: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated.
        !!
        
                ********************************************************************************
                Please avoid running ``setup.py`` and ``easy_install``.
                Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
                standards-based tools.
        
                See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/917 for details.
                ********************************************************************************
        
        !!
          easy_install.initialize_options(self)
        /home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py:66: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated.
        !!
        
                ********************************************************************************
                Please avoid running ``setup.py`` directly.
                Instead, use pypa/build, pypa/installer or other
                standards-based tools.
        
                See https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html for details.
                ********************************************************************************
        
        !!
          self.initialize_options()
        running egg_info
        writing python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/PKG-INFO
        writing dependency_links to python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
        writing requirements to python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/requires.txt
        writing top-level names to python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/top_level.txt
        reading manifest file 'python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
        writing manifest file 'python-sdk/nuscenes_devkit.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        running build_ext
        Creating /home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nuscenes-devkit.egg-link (link to python-sdk)
        Adding nuscenes-devkit 1.1.9 to easy-install.pth file
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
          File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
          File "/home/michaelresearch/git/perceptest/third_party/nuscenes-devkit/setup.py", line 27, in <module>
            setuptools.setup(
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 107, in setup
            return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 185, in setup
            return run_commands(dist)
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 201, in run_commands
            dist.run_commands()
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
            self.run_command(cmd)
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
            super().run_command(command)
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 988, in run_command
            cmd_obj.run()
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 34, in run
            self.install_for_development()
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/develop.py", line 126, in install_for_development
            self.process_distribution(None, self.dist, not self.no_deps)
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 726, in process_distribution
            self.update_pth(dist)
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1235, in update_pth
            self.pth_file.save()
          File "/home/michaelresearch/miniconda3/envs/research/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1642, in save
            self.dirty |= last_dirty or self.paths != self._init_paths
        TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |=: 'list' and 'bool'
        [end of output]
    
    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35363869)